# Deleted file still appears in Directory.GetFiles result

Tags: c#

I have two webmethods. The first is:

```
void deleteFile(string filePath)
{
  File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

The other is:

```
string[] getAllFile()
{
  // at the same folder....
  Directory.GetFiles("*.xml");
  .....
  return ....   
}
```

I'm calling these methods like so:

```
deleteFile("1.xml")
getAllFile();
```

Despite deleting the "1.xml" file, the call to `Directory.GetFiles("*.xml");` still returns "1.xml" in the results. In other words, it doesn't seem to have been deleted.

And then, when I loop the result ,  try to read the file  , get the FileNoFoundException

Comment: im sorry , i means , i had deleted the file , but , it had been searched by the directory.getfiles("*.xml");

Comment: @Scott: Do you mean that you intended to delete the file, but it did not appear to be deleted when you called getfiles?

Comment: Hi @Scott, you may wish to edit your question to make it clearer. Am I right in saying that even after you have called deleteFile("1.xml"), getAllFile() is still finding "1.xml"?

Comment: Does the worker process have the authority to commit the delete? If it is in a web method you have to look to see if the operation credentials of worker process has permissions to delete files in the filePath.

Comment: I think he means the file still shows up after he's called File.delete() to delete it.  The File.delete() method doesn't guarantee it will delete the file immediately, so it makes sense.

Comment: @0A0D thank you ! yes , it did not appear to be deleted when you called getfiles.

Comment: @Scott: is the file open elsewhere?

Comment: My issue with the same symptoms was that in my Visual Studio console application, it copied the entire directly to the bin folder and wasn't refreshing it on Solution Clean/Rebuild. Deleting bin & obj folders forces a refresh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found that the DirectoryInfo/FileInfo classes do not always update. In those instances you need to call the Refresh method on the Directory/File instances.

Comment: **What you mean** exactly? I called `Refresh()` on `DirectoryInfo` itself, and on each `FileInfo` from `GetFiles()`, and on each `DirectoryInfo` from `GetDirectories()`. Still, `GetFiles.Length` returns count with deleted files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but I suspect that result of your webmethods are being cached somewhere.