# Bug with File.Delete when using Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, .net, directory, delete-file

**Consider the following code:**

```
foreach(string file in Directory.GetFiles("C:\\DeleteTest"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
    FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);
    File.Delete(fileInfo.FullName);
}
```

**First iteration:**

```
C:\DeleteTest\File1.dat
C:\DeleteTest\File2.dat
C:\DeleteTest\File3.dat
```

**Second iteration:**

> (nothing)

The problem I am having is that I can still see the files (and open then) in Windows Explorer, so why on the second iteration are they not found by .NET?

**Issues:**

- Delete has not deleted the files
- They "appear" deleted to .NET but still exist in Windows Explorer

Comment: Does any process have open handles on these files?

Comment: A locked file would raise an IOException

Comment: I will be the first to ask if you have double checked the path in explorer is the same as that in your code

Comment: You could probably make sure the file is read-write

Comment: @Alex K, Yes the explorer path is the same - because I can perform other file actions, just not delete

Comment: A read-only attrib would generate an UnauthorizedAccessException

Comment: The files are not read-only

Comment: Run sysinternals *Process Monitor*, filtering for the console host process and see whats up

Comment: It might be a case of iterating a collection you are in the process of changing.

Comment: Ever considered using `DirectoryInfo("C:\\DeleteTest").GetFiles()` instead?

Comment: @Plutonix normally this incurs a runtime exception, however the collection itself is not changing - only the underlying files associated with the collection.

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6512072/) may be useful.